# Datatable não ordena o campo quando alterado o valor localmente

Tags: jquery, razor, jquery-datatables

Bom dia galera,

Estou usando o Datatable para fazer ordenação, porém quando altero o valor localmente do status e sem dar post na página o Datatable parece que ignora a minha alteração e ordena todos os outros mas o que eu acabei de alterar não é ordenado, como se eu nunca tivesse alterado o valor daquele campo.

Segue o código abaixo:

Jquery:

```
function IntanciaGrid() {

    $('#gridTable').DataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [3]
            }
        ],

        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "next": "Próximo",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            },
            "emptyTable": "Não foi possível encontrar nenhum registro!"
        },

    });
}
```

Esse é o botão que altera o status:

```
<button class="btn @(item.Ativo == 0 ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger") btn-xs btnAlteraStatus" type="button" data-id="@item.IdCurso">
    <i class="fa @(item.Ativo == 0 ? "fa-plus-circle" : "fa-minus-circle")"></i>
</button>
```

Grid:

```
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="gridTable">
                <thead style="background-color:#B2DFEE;">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="stf-aligntext" style="width:60%"><b>Cursos Técnicos e/ou FIC</b></th>
                        <th class="stf-aligntext" style="width:15%"><b>Tipo</b></th>
                        <th class="stf-aligntext" style="width:15%"><b>Status</b></th>
                        <th class="stf-aligntext" style="width:10%"><b>Ações</b></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (PronatecDados.DALC.Entities.Curso item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="stf-aligntext">@item.NomeCurso</td>
                            <td class="stf-aligntext">@(item.Tipo == 1 ? "Fic" : "Técnico")</td>
                            <td class="stf-aligntext">@(item.Ativo == 1 ? "Ativo" : "Inativo")</td>
                            <td class="stf-aligntext">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Cadastrar", "CursoProfissionalizante", new {id = @item.IdCurso })" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                </a>&nbsp;
                                <button class="btn @(item.Ativo == 0 ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger") btn-xs btnAlteraStatus" type="button" data-id="@item.IdCurso">
                                    <i class="fa @(item.Ativo == 0 ? "fa-plus-circle" : "fa-minus-circle")"></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Achei um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer:

Pesquiso o Campo Tokyo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Altero o valor apenas no HTML:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele não ordena, preciso que ordene...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou fazer o reload nela, após a alteração do valor?

Comment: Reload na Grid?

Comment: Sim. Na DataTables. https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: Não estou conseguindo fazer, pode me mostrar como devo inserir esse método?

Comment: Como está código da sua grid?

Comment: @Danilo, desculpe, não tinha colocado o código da grid, agora coloquei.

Answer (score -1):

Coloque o `"ordering": true` na função `InstanciaGrid()`:

```
function IntanciaGrid() {

    $('#gridTable').DataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [3]
            }
        ],
        //Inclua o ordering
        "ordering": true,
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "next": "Próximo",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            },
            "emptyTable": "Não foi possível encontrar nenhum registro!"
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou =/